# Transferring MAMP Pro to a new Mac that has a new username

Tags: apache, rename, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mamp-pro

The *mysql56* directory and *settings4.plist* copied over to the corresponding places on the new Mac. The problem is, I am using a different username on the new Mac so all of the virtualhosts paths (root directories) are incorrect – they include the former username.

Sure, I can manually update each one via MAMP Pro gui, but I have over 100 virtualhost names. I thought updating both httpd.conf files ( `~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/httpd.conf` and 
 `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf`) would resolve the issue, but it doesn't.

Instead, it re-writes both httpd.conf files back to the old username once Apache is started.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a late reply to when OP posted, but I recently encountered this problem too when transferring hard drives.

I was able to fix this by copying and replacing the full folders of BOTH:

`/Users/yourUserName/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO`
(minus the `db` folder unless you want to transfer those too)

and

`/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf`

Once I replaced these, all of my previous hard drive's virtual hosts appeared.

If your username and root directory are different, you most likely will need to do a text search and replace. Replace the old path with your new path on both `httpd.conf` files and the `httpd-ssl.conf` (if you used SSL) which are in the folders I listed above.

Comment: Hi, it's a little difficult to understand what exactly you're saying you did here, any chance you could elaborate a bit?

Comment: @3D1T0R sure. So say you're setting a MAMP Pro on a new computer and you still have file access to your old computer. After you install MAMP Pro on your new computer, locate the two folders indicated in the answer on both the old an new computer. Delete those folders on the new computer. Then copy and paste the those folders from the old computer to the new one. Once you start up MAMP, the virtual host list should be transferred.